# Pointing a domain name to my home web server

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, dns

So I have a home machine running Ubuntu Server 14.04 running an apache2 server. This machine is also running a Minecraft server. I set up my domain(example.com) host "A" type record with my WAN IP and I have port forwarded port 80 and 443 for my web server and 25565 for my Minecraft server using the LAN IP of my server. Here's my dilemma, I can access my Minecraft server using the domain (suggesting I set up the host records properly) but I can not access my test site from the outside world.

I know that my WAN IP is dynamic but only changes at the earliest on a monthly basis. So I'll deal with Dynamic DNS at a later time.

The funny thing is, when I enter my domain while connected to my home network everything works but this could be because of the way Virtual Hosts work with the server but I'm not sure.

My question is, can anyone provide some insight or suggestions on what to do to be able to view my test site running from my home server using my domain?

Comment: Who is your ISP (Internet Service Provider)?
what does your apache2.conf file look like?
as well as your .htaccess file? **remember to remove your external IP address (if you worry about such things) before posting**

Answer (score 2):

Does your browser report "Connection Timed Out" when you try to connect to port 80 or 443?

If it does, it's most likely because your ISP blocks incoming connections to those ports for "security reasons" (though most ISPs just don't want consumers running web servers without special plans).

There's no way of getting around this short of changing ports. Luckily for you, the secondary ports for HTTP and HTTPS usually aren't blocked by ISPs, and are accepted by modern browsers in terms of security. The secondary ports are `8080` for HTTP and `8443` for HTTPS. Change those ports and you should be able to connect.

On a slightly off-topic note, if you need a server manager for your Minecraft server, [PufferPanel](http://pufferpanel.com) is free and works rather well. I use it myself and find it's very handy for managing my MC servers remotely. It does take some setup, but the setup is well documented and isn't too difficult.

Comment: The browser says "could not open the page because the server stopped responding". That's a good point that my ISP may block those ports I'll try and find out and in the mean time I'll open 8080 and 8443. Also thanks for the recommendation, definitely going to try to implement PufferPanel :)

Comment: When entering my domain, do I need to use :8080 or do browsers know its a secondary default http port?

Comment: @MikeyC343 Browsers assume port 80 or port 443. Any other port you'll have to specify like `example.com:8080`.